# Moving a YouTube URL from one account to another

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

My friend has the URL `youtube.com/name` under his YouTube account which I want to transfer to my Google account.

When I type in the URL `youtube.com/name` I am redirected to another URL `youtube.com/c/name2`, which is also owned by my friend.

1. Does anyone know what this URL is referred to in Googles internal? (Is this a channel?)
2. Do you know where my friend can login on his google or YouTube account to manage redirects and hopefully also transfer the URL's?

Answer (score 0):

He has to choose another `youtube.com/another_name` and then you could ask for `youtube.com/name` from account settings if you satisfy the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are referring is the channel URL, instructions to setup and modify channel URL can be found at https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2657968?hl=en

For transferring channels, your best options is to convert the YouTube channel to a Brand Account, details can be found here:
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9367690?hl=en